# AspNet Identity 2 Modifying table names

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to modify the orrible and insane tables names in example from AspNetUsers to Users.

My project is a **WebForm WebSite Project**.
I'm using **Visual Studio 2012**, **Entity Framework 6 and Framework 4.5**.
I've setup the entire Identity stuff, and **everything is working fine**.

Now I need to change tables names.
If I put only the following code:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    }
```

in the ApplicationDbContext class, it's not executed, and if I try to change manually the table names I get the error:

Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'

So following some suggestions I try to run **enable-migrations Add-Migration and Update-Database** commands, but from I get on the very first one the following error:

```
PM> enable-migrations -verbose
```

Using StartUp project 'MyProjectName'.
Using NuGet project 'MyProjectName'.
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Server stack trace: 
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Please give me some directions as I don't know where to put my hands anymore.
Thanks

Comment: If I run the website in debug mode, OnModelCreating() is never called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

**EntityFramework doesn't have full support for Web Site Project**
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/568

So the only way is to create a **Web Application project** and migrate all the existing code.